# AWS instance auto creation while performing operation in s3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created a script to upload files to amazon s3 bucket.
here is the code to do that.

```
public static AmazonS3 getS3Client(String accessKey, String secretKey) {

    if (oldAccessKey.equals(accessKey) && oldSecretKey.equals(secretKey) && s3client != null)
        return s3client;

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    oldAccessKey = accessKey;
    oldSecretKey = secretKey;
    // create a client connection based on credentials
    s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    return s3client;
}

public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, File file, AmazonS3 client) {
    System.out.println("File Name to upload: " + file.getName());
    client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, file.getName(), file)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
}
```

But when i ran this script to upload 10 files, i saw 10 different instance created to handle the request. Is it because of this script.

Is it possible that this script has instantiated multiple instances.
Or is it just co-incidence that somebody has hacked the account on AWS and created instances.

If there is some hacking involved i would love to know how it's done.

Comment: *10 different instances* ... EC2 instances?!

Comment: yes those were EC2 instances